# Stream two list and return descriptions

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list optionDetails and in it another list called content. I want to match those content with another array and return the descriptions from the second array

[image]

second array has 90 items in the optionCodeContent. I want to match the  option code in the first array with the optionCode in the optionCodeContent array and return its optionDescription in the second array.

[image]

Im not very good with java 8 streams and i dont know where to begin.

i need to match the option codes so i can get the right descriptions into another arraylist. In the end, i should have two descriptions in another arraylist

Comment: If you already have them in lists, why do you think you need to use streams?

Comment: i need to match the option codes so i can get the right descriptions into another arraylist

Comment: If you're not good with streams, then don't use them. You can always use a regular loop

Comment: Convert your lookup list into a `Map` and reference keys.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a `stream` from the `optionDetails` array, then map it to a `String` that gets its value from an inner stream of `optionCodeContent`. It's funky but it works.

```
optionDetails.stream()
  .map(optionItem -> optionCodeContent.stream()
     .filter(occ -> occ.optionCode.equals(optionItem.optionCode))
     .findFirst().get())
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Better to convert `optionCodeContent` to a map first rather than use `filter().findFirst`. You're constantly scanning over the same items

Comment: How does this handle null values?